# The intersection of the associated primes of a reduced ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R $ be a commutative ring with identity. Recall that a prime ideal is called associated prime ideal whenever it is the annihilator of a nonzero element. Also a ring is called reduced whenever has no nonzero nilpotent.

> Why is zero the intersection of all associated  prime ideals of a reduced ring?

Comment: a nonzero element.... of $R$?  Associated primes are usually defined with respect to a given module $M$.  Are we supposed to assume $M=R$ or something?

Comment: Yes. A prime ideal is a associated prime ideal of an $R $-module, if there exists a non zero element of that module such that the prime ideal is its annihilator.

Comment: I already knew everything after "yes", and it is not relevant to my question. Does your "yes" mean you are confirming that you are talking about *a nonzero element of $R$* or do you mean something else (all associated primes for all $R$ modules?)

Comment: About non zero elements of $R $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We denote by ${\rm Ass}(R)$ the set of associated primes of $R$ and by ${\rm Ass}^f(R)$ the set of weakly associated primes of $R$.

(1) By Bourbaki, AC.IV.1 Exercice 17 b), we have $\bigcap{\rm Ass}^f(R)={\rm Nil}(R)$. Thus, if $R$ is reduced, then $\bigcap{\rm Ass}^f(R)=0$.

(2) If $R$ is noetherian, then by Bourbaki, AC.IV.1 Exercice 17 g) we have ${\rm Ass}^f(R)={\rm Ass}(R)$, and therefore $\bigcap{\rm Ass}(R)={\rm Nil}(R)$ by (1). Thus, if $R$ is reduced and noetherian, then $\bigcap{\rm Ass}(R)=0$.

(3) There exists a non-noetherian reduced ring $R$ such that $\bigcap{\rm Ass}(R)=0$. For this it suffices to exhibit a non-noetherian reduced ring $R$ such that ${\rm Ass}^f(R)={\rm Ass}(R)$. Such an example (with $R$ even a domain) is given in P.-J. Cahen, *Ascending chain conditions and associated primes,* Commutative ring theory (Fès, 1992), 41-46, Lecture Notes in Pure and Appl. Math. 153, Dekker, New York, 1994.

(4) There exists a reduced ring $R$ such that $\bigcap{\rm Ass}(R)\neq 0$. For this, any nonzero reduced ring $R$ with ${\rm Ass}(R)=\emptyset$ will do.

(Thanks to user25867 for pointing out how to improve statement (1).)

Comment: I think the nilradical equals the intersection of all weakly associated primes for any commutative ring, no need to assume that R is reduced. And this is the way one should read Bernard's answer.

Comment: @user26857: Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of all associated prime ideals is the *nilradical* of $R$, i.e. the set of nilpotent elements. If the ring is reduced, this set is $\{0\}$.

Comment: I've seen that the nilradical is this intersection for *Noetherian* rings but does it hold in general?

Comment: I believe this is true with correct notion of associated primes (*weakly associated prime ideals* – which are the same if the ring is noetherian).

Comment: The intersection of all minimal prime ideals is the nilradical of $R $. I want to know  why it is true for associated primes in reduced rings, with the mentioned definition?

Comment: The minimal primes are weakly associated (cf Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. IV *Associated Prime Ideals and Primary Decomposition*, §1, exercise 17..

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the reference...

Comment: [This](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546) seems like it might contain everything needed to prove the above claims.

Comment: @Bernard,  why is the intersection of all associated prime ideals a nilradical of $R$?

Comment: @Es.Ro: A nilpotent element obviously belongs to each prime ideal. Conversely, if $x$ is non-nilpotent, consider the set $S$ of all $x^k\; k\in\mathbf N$. It is a  multiplicative subset of the ring which doesn't contain $0$, hence there exists a prime ideal which does not contain $S$, in particular, it does not contain $x$.

Comment: @Bernard, This is the standard argument to show that the nilradical is the set of nilpotent elements. In your argument why that prime ideal is an associated prime ideal of $R $, that is, why that prime ideal is the annihilator of a nonzero element of $R $?

Comment: That's because one shows $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Ass} A$ have the same minimal elements.

Comment: @Bernard, this is not true for an arbitrary commutative ring.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can replace *associated* with *weakly associated*.